# How to BCNF decompose when an attribute has no relation with any others

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

**Assignment:**

> Consider a relation (,,,,,,) and its FD set  = { → ,  → ,  → ,  → ,  → ,  → }. 
>   Decompose it into a collection of BCNF relations if it is not in BCNF. Make sure your decomposition is lossless-join.

**Explanation**

Hi, I'm working on my database homework (relation design chapter).
I think I've commanded the basic process based on in-class examples.
However, the tricky part here is we have an attribute 'H' which has no relation with others, which confuses me deeply.  How should I handle it?

**Attempted answer**

```
•   We start from a schema: ABCDEGH, since H has no relations with any attribute, we decompose it into tables: H and ABCDEG
•   The FDs for ABCDEG remains the same, therefore key is E.
•   The FD D →AG violates BCNF (FD with non-key on LHS).
•   To fix, we need to decompose into tables: ADG and BCDE
•   FDs for ADG are { D → AG }, therefore key is D, therefore BCNF.
•   FDs for BCDE are { B → CD,  E → D,  BC → DE, E → B, CD → BE }
•   Key for BCDE is also E, and FD B → CD violates BCNF (FD with non-key on LHS).
•   To fix, we need to decompose into tables: BCD and BE
•   FDs for BCD are { B → CD } therefore key is B, therefore BCNF.
•   FDs for BE are { E → B } therefore key is E, therefore BCNF.
•   Final schema:  H, ADG, BCD, BE
```

What are your comments about my mistakes?

Comment: Step 1 is wrong. What reference are you using?

Comment: What does "remains the same" mean? Do you realize AB is also a CK? Do you realize a relation can have multiple CKs? Please when you are following an algorithm give it or a reference to it, not just a (partial) trace of your following it. Also, "has no relation with others" uses "relation" in a generic way in a context that uses it differently as a technical term. You mean that H is not mentioned in any FDs with any other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Your first bullet is wrong. If you go to a reference like a published academic textbook that has a correct BCNF decomposition algorithm then it will not have that step.