# Decomposing into BCNF when an attribute doesn't have a FD

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I'm sitting with a database exercise which includes decomposing a relation R into BCNF. I've tried to follow the BCNF algorithm but I don't really understand how it works.

The relation is R(AXYS) and the FDs A -> X, X -> Z, Z -> A. I realized one relation should be (AXY) but what happens when Y doesn't have a FD? Where do I put Y?

Comment: Hi. Quote your textbook and/or the algorithm you are following & show your work following it. The algorithm already says "what happens when" anything comes up. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Also always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to BCNF decompose when an attribute has no relation with any others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43181422/3404097). But I can't vote to close this as a duplicate of that one because that one doesn't have an upvote or accept. So if the other one helps you please upvote it & I'll record the duplication. PS I found it by *googling your title*: 'stackoverflow.com (Decomposing OR decomposition) into BCNF when an attribute doesn't have a FD'. (It happened to be answered by me.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to BCNF decompose when an attribute has no relation with any others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181422/how-to-bcnf-decompose-when-an-attribute-has-no-relation-with-any-others)

Comment: @Renzo Ah, teamwork!

Comment: @philipxy, yes!

Comment: There is no Z attribute in R, but there are FDs X -> Z, Z -> A. This does not make sense. Please correct. Is S a typo for Z?